# Write files in folder Windows10 vs Ubuntu

Tags: c++, ubuntu, fstream

So the following code works perfectly in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows10 , but doesn't on my Ubuntu virtual machine in codeblocks. The program is supposed to take from a .txt file usernames line by line, then in a separate folder create .txts with names created from combining 2 different usernames.

What could be the reason for this? And is there any way to work around this, besides adding code to delete

EXAMPLE usernames.txt

user11

user22

user33

Expected result: user11user22.txt , user11user33.txt, user22user33.txt

Ubuntu result: user11.txt, user11user22.txt , user11user33.txt, user22.txt,  user22user33.txt, user33.txt

```
ifstream fin("usernames.txt");
string user1;

while (getline(fin, user1))
    allUsers.push_back(user1);

for (int i = 0; i < allUsers.size(); i++)
{
    char fileArgument[60];
    strcpy(fileArgument, "PRIVATEHISTORY/");
    strcat(fileArgument, allUsers[i].c_str());
    for (int j = i+1; j < allUsers.size(); j++)
    {
        char temp[60];
        strcpy(temp, fileArgument); 
        strcat(temp, allUsers[j].c_str());
        strcat(temp, ".txt");

        cout << temp << '\n';

        FILE* x = fopen(temp, "w");
        fclose(x);
    }
    cout << '\n';
}
```

***cout results on Windows10 / VS2017***

[image]

***cout results on Ubuntu/Codeblocks***

[image]

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? Even a series of print lines will probably show you where things have gone wrong. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I would forget about the c-string and strcat ... and just use `std::string`.

Comment: You may want to print the line before `allUsers.push_back(user1);` to see what is displayed.

Comment: You should compile your code with all warnings & debug info: `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g`. You should [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). And you need to read more about Linux programming, see [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) and [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html). Linux & Windows are different operating systems. Your *fix-my-code* question without an [MCVE] is **off-topic** on SO

Answer (score -1):

Aparently the extra \n -s in the usernames.txt was causing it...